# Conditional replacement of values in column A, B, C with value in column D

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalization, hierarchy

I'm cleaning up a messy data source describing a hierarchical structure identified as follows. I'm using Python and pandas.

```
¦ A ¦ B ¦ C ¦ D ¦
-----------------
¦ x ¦   ¦   ¦ a ¦
¦   ¦ x ¦   ¦ b ¦
¦   ¦   ¦ x ¦ c ¦
¦   ¦   ¦ x ¦ d ¦
¦ x ¦   ¦   ¦ e ¦
¦   ¦ x ¦   ¦ f ¦
¦   ¦   ¦ x ¦ g ¦
¦   ¦   ¦ x ¦ h ¦
```

I'd like to generate unique IDs that also keep the hierarchical nature of the data. (Names per parent are unique, do not focus on that part please.)

```
¦ A ¦ B ¦ C ¦ D ¦ ID    ¦
-------------------------
¦ x ¦   ¦   ¦ a ¦ a     ¦
¦   ¦ x ¦   ¦ b ¦ a.b   ¦
¦   ¦   ¦ x ¦ c ¦ a.b.c ¦
¦   ¦   ¦ x ¦ d ¦ a.b.d ¦
¦ x ¦   ¦   ¦ e ¦ e     ¦ <-- note, this is NOT e.b.d,
¦   ¦ x ¦   ¦ f ¦ e.f   ¦     so when parent changes
¦   ¦   ¦ x ¦ g ¦ e.f.g ¦     fillna must not be applied
¦   ¦   ¦ x ¦ h ¦ e.f.h ¦
```

My strategy is:

1. replace 'x' values in A, B, C with value from D
2. use pandas' forward na fill
3. concatenate A, B and C into column ID

2 and 3 are easy, but I can not pass 1. I can replace the x-es with a single value:

```
df[df.loc[:,'A':'C'] == 'x'] = 1
```

but that does not work if I try to pass `df.D` instead of `1`.

Please recommend an elegant pythonic solution.

---

Source to work with:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA=StringIO("""
A;B;C;D;solution
x;;;x;x
;x;;a;xa
;x;;b;xb
;x;;c;xc
;;x;1;xc1
;;x;2;xc2
;x;;d;xd
;;x;3;xd3
;;x;4;xd4
x;;;y;y
;x;;e;ye
;;x;5;ye5
;;x;6;ye6
;x;;f;yf
;;x;7;yf7
;;x;8;yf8
;;x;9;yf9""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";", header=False)
```

Comment: can you give your input `df`?

Comment: yes, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: what would be the result on the 6th line of your dataframe for example?

Comment: x.c.2 - logic shown in 4th and 8th lines of example. (Sorry for providing different example and testdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest ever, but something like

```
w0 = df.iloc[:,:3]
wx = w0 == 'x'
wempty = (wx.cumsum(axis=1) >= 1).shift(axis=1).fillna(False)
wfilled = w0.where(~wx, df.D, axis=0).ffill()
w = w0.where(wempty, wfilled, axis=1).fillna('')
df["new_solution"] = w.apply('.'.join,axis=1).str.rstrip(".")
```

gives me

```
>>> df
      A    B    C  D solution new_solution
0     x  NaN  NaN  x        x            x
1   NaN    x  NaN  a       xa          x.a
2   NaN    x  NaN  b       xb          x.b
3   NaN    x  NaN  c       xc          x.c
4   NaN  NaN    x  1      xc1        x.c.1
5   NaN  NaN    x  2      xc2        x.c.2
6   NaN    x  NaN  d       xd          x.d
7   NaN  NaN    x  3      xd3        x.d.3
8   NaN  NaN    x  4      xd4        x.d.4
9     x  NaN  NaN  y        y            y
10  NaN    x  NaN  e       ye          y.e
11  NaN  NaN    x  5      ye5        y.e.5
12  NaN  NaN    x  6      ye6        y.e.6
13  NaN    x  NaN  f       yf          y.f
14  NaN  NaN    x  7      yf7        y.f.7
15  NaN  NaN    x  8      yf8        y.f.8
16  NaN  NaN    x  9      yf9        y.f.9
```

The trick here is the use of `cumsum`, which lets us distinguish the cells which should be empty from the cells which should be filled.

Comment: I will break down your answer to the smallest detail and will make a living from what I learn. :jawdropped:

Comment: I'd appreciate your feedback on solution below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37009971/1486768

Answer (score 1):

You can use ix instead of loc:

```
df.ix[df.ix[:,'A'] == 'x','A'] = df.ix[df.ix[:,'A'] == 'x','D']
df.ix[df.ix[:,'B'] == 'x','B'] = df.ix[df.ix[:,'B'] == 'x','D']
df.ix[df.ix[:,'C'] == 'x','C'] = df.ix[df.ix[:,'C'] == 'x','D']
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid repetitions and for loops when working with data. Yet, this still can come out as winner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame([np.where(df[n]=='x', df['D'], df[n]) for n in ['A','B','C']]).T

dt.ffill().fillna('').apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x), axis=1).str.replace('\.+$','')

Out[213]:
0         x
1       x.a
2       x.b
3       x.c
4     x.c.1
5     x.c.2
6     x.d.2
7     x.d.3
8     x.d.4
9     y.d.4
10    y.e.4
11    y.e.5
12    y.e.6
13    y.f.6
14    y.f.7
15    y.f.8
16    y.f.9
dtype: object
```

Comment: I got this far (in a less sophisticated way, using `df.fillna()`), but there is a major issue with our solution. `6` should be `x.d`, `9` should be `y`, and so on - we fill those NAs, that should not be filled. I think there must be a step before the `fillna()` that replaces NAs with `''`s in every cells where `parent_n <> parent_n-1`.

Comment: I'm starting to think that `awk` is more suitable for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally came to this solution using some tricks by @DSM.

It has only one temporary variable and solves the problem mainly with boolean masking.

```
# bool mask for empty cells that have non-empty cell before them
nofills = (df.iloc[:,:3] == 'x').cumsum(axis=1) & ((df.iloc[:,:3] == 'x') == False) > 0

# fill these with empty strings
df[nofills] = ''

# replace 'x'es with values from column D, ffill up NaNs then concat together into a new column
df['solution2'] = df.iloc[:,:3].where(df.iloc[:,:3] != 'x', df.D, axis=0).ffill().apply(''.join, axis=1)

print df
```

Results:

```
      A    B  C  D solution solution2
0     x          x        x         x
1   NaN    x     a       xa        xa
2   NaN    x     b       xb        xb
3   NaN    x     c       xc        xc
4   NaN  NaN  x  1      xc1       xc1
5   NaN  NaN  x  2      xc2       xc2
6   NaN    x     d       xd        xd
7   NaN  NaN  x  3      xd3       xd3
8   NaN  NaN  x  4      xd4       xd4
9     x          y        y         y
10  NaN    x     e       ye        ye
11  NaN  NaN  x  5      ye5       ye5
12  NaN  NaN  x  6      ye6       ye6
13  NaN    x     f       yf        yf
14  NaN  NaN  x  7      yf7       yf7
15  NaN  NaN  x  8      yf8       yf8
16  NaN  NaN  x  9      yf9       yf9
```

Any comment / recommendation is highly appreciated.